# Query User rule blocking packet despite Windows Firewall Exemption

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, port, windows-firewall

I have created a Windows Firewall exemption via an Inbound Rule allowing UDP traffic through local port 51820 from any remote port.

I have validated via the Windows Event Viewer that my simple PING test is being dropped and I corresponded the filter-run-time-id to the Windows Firewall rule, `Query User`.

I read that other people fixed the issue by modifying Group Policy to apply local firewall rules. In my case, this value is already set to `Yes` for Public Networks (the type of network my PC is connected to.)

What else can I investigate? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

running a PING will not guarantee the check if the port is open, PING will use icmp protocol, not UDP.

One way you can check is using [nmap](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/nmap-command-linux-examples) from a linux computer or just try with one of the online tools like [this one](https://www.ipvoid.com/udp-port-scan/) to see if your port is actually open.

for what I remember what you did should be enough, enabling the inbound rule and applying the local policy to public networks, but [in case we are missing something](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/create-an-inbound-port-rule)

Also as a test you can try disabling you windows firewall temporarily to see if your service is responding correctly over that port.